# How to add name to each step in jenkins pipeline stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

```
stage('type checking') {
     steps {
          script {
              docker.image('node:8').inside() {
                   sh '''
                   npm run lint
                   npm run type-check
                        '''
               }
           }
      }
 }
```

I want to separate `npm run lint` and `npm run type-check` into 2 steps and give each a meaningful name. how to give a name for each step?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this can help:

```
               sh 'npm run lint &'
               sh 'npm run type-check &'
```